# Break echo output based on value from column in database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, mysqli

I have 5 tables in a database:

- `players` (for general info about player)
- `seasons` (table for seasons)
- `clubs` (tables for general info about club)
- `playerstats` (table for players statistics, apps, goals)
- `clubseason` (table thats connecting clubs and seasons and for clubs statistics)

I want to echo statistics for players by praticular season in this format:

```
**1. CLUB 1** 
Players from that club (club 1) in that season (apps/goals) etc
**2. CLUB 2** 
Players from club 2 with stats
etc 
sorted based on club positions in that season
```

I have developed php code

```
<?php
include('connect-mysql.php');
$sqlchc = "SELECT jos_igraciDB_season.idSeason, jos_igraciDB_season.seasonURL FROM jos_igraciDB_season ORDER BY `jos_igraciDB_season`.`idSeason`";
$res = mysql_query($sqlchc);
$article_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');
while($rowt=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  if ($article_id == $rowt['seasonURL']) {
    $urlID = $rowt['idSeason']; 
  }
}
$sqlcom = "SELECT jos_clubseason.clubposition, jos_players.firstName, jos_players.lastName, jos_players.position, jos_players.playerpic, jos_playerstats.idClub, jos_playerstats.idSeason, jos_igraciDB_club.name, jos_playerstats.apps, jos_playerstats.goals, jos_players.idPlayer
 FROM `jos_playerstats` JOIN `jos_igraciDB_club` ON `jos_playerstats`.`idClub` = `jos_igraciDB_club`.`idClub` JOIN `jos_igraciDB_season` ON `jos_playerstats`.`idSeason` = `jos_igraciDB_season`.`idSeason` JOIN `jos_players` ON `jos_playerstats`.`idPlayer` = `jos_players`.`idPlayer` JOIN `jos_clubseason` ON `jos_playerstats`.`idClub` = `jos_clubseason`.`idClub` WHERE `jos_playerstats`.`idSeason` = '".$urlID."' AND `jos_clubseason`.`idSeason` = '".$urlID."' ORDER BY clubposition, position";
$result = mysql_query($sqlcom);
$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<strong>'.$row2['clubposition'].'. '.$row2['name'].'</strong>';   echo '<p>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo '{modal igraci/article/'.$row['idPlayer'].'|width=500|height=400|title='.mb_strtoupper($row['lastName'], 'UTF-8').' '.mb_strtoupper($row['firstName'], 'UTF-8').'}'.$row['firstName'].' '.mb_strtoupper($row['lastName'], 'UTF-8').' ('.$row['apps'].'/'.$row['goals'].'){/modal} ; '; 
} 
?>
```

I get something like this on output: 
[image: echo output for stats]

So basicily I want to split after each club output in this example

1. Građanski (Zagreb) then after Franz MANTLER (who is last player in this club) to be next line then next club
2. SAŠK (Sarajevo) who will began with Josip DVORŽAK player

Can be done? I think it can, please help me with suggestions and answers what to do and break output.

Comment: It's called a line break.  For browser output, it's called HTML ^

Comment: You didnt get a point what I want to do...Somehow I want to break my echo into while loop. Or to reorganize maybe SQL command to get what I want.

Comment: Why are you including a file to connect to the database and then start using `mysql_*` functions (which are deprecated)? You should really be using the Joomla API if you're using Joomla

Comment: I also did explain pretty enough what I want to do! Please read from point to top my question.

Comment: Add a line break when there is a new club in the loop...

Comment: Lodder. Yeah, but this is just beta version...Without Joomla API - because writing MySQL clauses in Joomla API is little to big. I want later to develop plugin, similar to JoomSport but to be free and much better. This is for now just for me and my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first - you missing first player. This is first line of result with first player in first club, but you output only club name

```
echo '<strong>'.$row2['clubposition'].'. '.$row2['name'].'</strong>';
```

and easiest way to achieve what you want is store clubposition and compare it.

```
$currentClub = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       if ($row2['clubposition'] != $currentClub) {
            $currentClub = $row2['clubposition'];
            echo '<strong>'.$row2['clubposition'].'. '.$row2['name'].'</strong>';   echo '<p>';
       }
       echo '{modal igraci/article/'.$row['idPlayer'].'|width=500|height=400|title='.mb_strtoupper($row['lastName'], 'UTF-8').' '.mb_strtoupper($row['firstName'], 'UTF-8').'}'.$row['firstName'].' '.mb_strtoupper($row['lastName'], 'UTF-8').' ('.$row['apps'].'/'.$row['goals'].'){/modal} ; <br/>'; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I gonna try right now. I had storing clubposition in clubseason table.